# HTML Materialize - "halfway-fab" icon lower portion is going behind the card reveal class

Tags: html, materialize

Good day everyone im trying to learn to code html while under the ongoing quarantine and i have no one to ask about this.

the problem is im trying to put a floating button on a card-reveal but the lower part of the float button goes under the "card" when put into the divider of the card using the "halfway-fab" class.

```html
 <div class="col s12 l3 push-l3">
            <div class="card z-depth-3">
                <div class="card-image waves-effect waves-block waves-light">
                  <a href="" class="left halfway-fab btn-floating blue pulse">
                    <i class="large material-icons">facebook</i>
                  </a>
                    <img class="activator"src="img/sean.jpg" alt="" class="responsive-img">
                </div>
                <div class="card-content">
                    <span class="card-title activator">Trapcccy
                      <i class="material-icons right">more_vert</i>
                      
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="card-reveal">
                  <span class="card-title">Writter
                    <i class="material-icons right">close</i></span>
                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatum voluptate porro voluptates autem delectus, numquam ex eligendi ipsa quia itaque quos! Necessitatibus suscipit aliquid exercitationem asperiores! Possimus odio commodi aspernatur.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

[image: image of problem]

Comment: Your code snippet isn't working (please update), but this is possibly just a z-index issue. Try increasing for the FAB.

Answer (score 0):

Some classes have `overflow: hidden` that prevents the float button from  being completely revealed. In your case the problem is in the class `waves-effect`. The same applies to the card classes `small`, `medium` and `large`. As you can see, `overflow: visible` applied to the `card-image` div solves the problem. However the waves effect is applied to the entire card. So you have to deal with this issue.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col s12 m6">
    <div class="card">
      <!-- as shown below, visible overflow solves the problem -->
      <div class="card-image waves-effect waves-block waves-light" style="overflow: visible">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/200">
        <span class="card-title">Card Title</span>
        <a class="btn-floating halfway-fab waves-effect waves-light red">
          <!-- can't attach an icon to the snippet -->
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="card-content">
        <p>I am a very simple card. I am good at containing small bits of information. I am convenient because I require little markup to use effectively.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```